# Enabling users to enter their email when they login with Twitter (OmniAuth)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I'm using [omniauth-twitter](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter) and I have everything set up:

**user.rb:**

```
  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
      user.email = auth["info"]["email"]
      # To pass password validation
      user.password = user.password_confirmation = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(n=6) 
    end
  end
```

**sessions_controller.rb:**

```
 def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

The problem is that you can't retrieve an email address from Twitter, so the login fails because of my validation rules:

**user.rb:**

```
 before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
```

I want to enable users to enter an email so they can login without failing the validation (only with Twitter, since I have Facebook and Google login too).

Does anyone have any suggestion?

**EDIT:**

**users_controller.rb:**

```
 def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      if params[:form_name] == "enter_email"
        render 'enter_email'
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end
  end
```

**users/enter_email.html.erb:**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Enter your email') %>
<h1>Enter your email</h1>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="span6 offset3">
        <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
          <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.text_field :email %>

          <%= f.hidden_field :provider, value: params[:oprovider] %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :provider, value: params[:oprovider] %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :uid, value: params[:ouid] %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :name, value: params[:oname] %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :password , value: params[:opassword] %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :password_confirmation, value: params[:opassword_confirmation] %>

          <% # To know to which form to redirect in case of validation error %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'form_name', 'enter_email' %>

          <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user is created it will be invalid since it will be missing the required email. So when the user save fails, you should put the information you retrieved from Twitter in the session and redirect the user to a registration page where he can input his email. Basically, this:

```
# SessionsController
def create

  if user.save
    sign_in user
    redirect_to ...
  else
    session[:omniauth] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except('extra')
    redirect_to new_registration_path
  end

end
```

You'll notice that we are discarding the `extra` hash because it usually contains a lot of information that we don't need. If you do need it, be careful because the session has a certain size limit and sometimes you can't fit everything in there.

Now you need to create a registrations controller with the `new` action (to show a page where the user will input his email) and the `create` action (where you will use the Twitter info to further customize your new user).

```
# RegistrationsController
def create
  if session[:omniauth]
    user = User.create_with_email_and_omniauth(params[:user], session[:omniauth])
  end
  session[:omniauth] = nil unless user.new_record?
end
```

Finally, if the user is valid and saved then we can safely destroy the Twitter info from the session.

Comment: Do I have to create a new `registration` controller? Since I already have a `user controller` and a `create` action in it, can I just use that one? Sorry, I'm a a little bit new to Rails, how do I use the code you provided above in conjunction with the 'enter_email` form? (Please see my **EDIT**)

Comment: Mmm...I think I have to create a `create_with_omniauth` action in the user's controller, right? And use that action in the form?

Comment: Yes, your controller doesn't have to be named `registrations`, that was only a suggestion. Now, you can use your `users controller` but it may depend on a lot of things. When is that `create` action called? That is pretty important.

Comment: Also, in your `user.rb` file you have a method called `create_with_omniauth` to which you pass the omniauth info to create a user. Well now you need a method (inside `user.rb`) that receives the omniauth info (which is stored in the session) and the email sent by the form to create a user. In your `create` action, if you are simply doing `@user = User.new(params[:user])` then you are **not** using the omniauth info stored in the session.

Comment: But why have that method inside `user.rb`?

Comment: OK, thanks, I made it work (but I did `session[:omniauth] = user` instead. Not sure whats the difference but it was more clear to me.

Comment: Well, just don't forget to destroy that info from the session after creating the user with `session[:omniauth] = nil unless user.new_record?`.