# Storing user data in a session and use it later in a form (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have an `omniauth_create` action in my **sessions** controller. It redirects the user to a view called **enter_email.html.erb** and passes some `params` to the redirect (fetched from [omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki)):

```
  def omniauth_create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    .
    .
    .
    else
      redirect_to(enter_email_path(oprovider: user.provider,
                                   ouid: user.uid,
                                   oname: user.name,
                                   opassword: user.password,
                                   opassword_confirmation: user.password))
    end
  end
```

Where they are used in hidden fields (basically a registration form):

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.hidden_field :provider, value: params[:oprovider] %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :provider, value: params[:oprovider] %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :uid, value: params[:ouid] %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :name, value: params[:oname] %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :password , value: params[:opassword] %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :password_confirmation, value: params[:opassword_confirmation] %>

      <% # To know to which form to redirect in case of validation error %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'form_name', 'enter_email' %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

Now the problem is that when there is validation error (e.g. the email had been already taken). The view renders `enter_email` and the `params` are wiped out from the hidden fields (from value).

So I was thinking of storing the data in a **session** instead of passing them with `redirect_to` I have never used sessions this way, so I'm a bit lost (I'm not even sure if I still need the hidden fields if I store data in a session?)

Can anyone give me a hint or an example?

Comment: Why aren't you asking this in your original question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210062/enabling-users-to-enter-their-email-when-they-login-with-twitter-omniauth/13225258
If you don't ask for any clarification and just upvote there's no way for me to know that my answer was not clear enough.

Comment: @Ashitaka Sorry, I just wanted to be more specific in this question (e.g. showing the omniauth data). In the previous question, I was a bit confused about how the code is fetching the attributes, and how to put that into the form I'm presenting int his question.

Comment: But like I said in my answer, the only thing you need to do is put the omniauth data inside the session with the simple line of code `session[:omniauth] = request.env['omniauth.auth']`. You can then retrieve it by simply calling `session[:omniauth]`. What's so complicated about that? Putting all the omniauth information in the url and then using it to fill hidden inputs is really tacky. Like I said, you should have asked for further help, not ask another question.

Comment: @Ashitaka OK, I will ask for clarification in the previous question.